# MYSQL: Howto get last download from 2 joined tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, left-join

This is my first question, so please be nice :)

I have this:

```
mysql> select cat_id, cat_name from phpbb_dm_eds_cat;
+--------+----------+
| cat_id | cat_name |
+--------+----------+
|      9 | catx     |
|     10 | cat2     |
|     11 | test     |
+--------+----------+

mysql> select subcat_id, subcat_name from phpbb_dm_eds_subcat;
+-----------+--------------+
| subcat_id | subcat_name  |
+-----------+--------------+
|        39 | aaa          |
|        40 | xxx111       |
|        41 | TESTXX       |
|        42 | xxa          |
+-----------+--------------+
```

Here is the download table:

```
mysql> select download_id, download_title, download_cat_id from phpbb_dm_eds;
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
| download_id | download_title | download_cat_id |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
|           3 | s              |               9 |
|           5 | raver          |              41 |
|           6 | hans           |              10 |
|           7 | readme         |              42 |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

Now the query:

```
mysql>
SELECT bc.cat_name, bc.cat_id,
    COUNT(bd.download_id) AS number_downloads,
    MAX(bd.last_changed_time) AS last_download
FROM phpbb_dm_eds_cat bc
LEFT JOIN phpbb_dm_eds bd ON bd.download_cat_id = bc.cat_id
GROUP BY bc.cat_id   ;

+----------+--------+------------------+---------------+
| cat_name | cat_id | number_downloads | last_download |
+----------+--------+------------------+---------------+
| catx     |      9 |                1 |    1427072549 |
| cat2     |     10 |                1 |    1427125950 |
| test     |     11 |                0 |          NULL |
+----------+--------+------------------+---------------+
```

the 'test' category has a subcategory which has a download in the subcat table, the categories 'catx' and 'cat2' have downloads too, there the last download is displayed correctly but i want the last_download in the subcat 'test' to be displayed too

How do I write the query?

Comment: Your 2nd-last paragraph is unintelligible. (I have edited a bit.) Please be more clear. Please use multiple sentences. Do you want the last_download of *every* subcat table subcategory? If yes then why mention 'test'?

Comment: This design is virtually unworkable

Comment: Give your table definitions. Also explain your tables. You say a "category has a subcategory" but where does the database hold that information? Act on my comment above.

Comment: 1. You have still not addressed all my comments. 2. Since you have still not explained what you want your query to return, please finish the following sentence: A row should be in the query result if and only if EITHER category named `cat_name` has id `cat_id`, number of downloads `number_downloads` and last download `last_download` OR subcategory named `cat_name` has id `cat_id` and ... ? 3. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You are not clear about what you want but it might be:

```
SELECT bc.cat_name, bc.cat_id,
    COUNT(bd.download_id) AS number_downloads,
    MAX(bd.last_changed_time) AS last_download
FROM (
        select cat_id, cat_name from phpbb_dm_eds_cat
    union
        select subcat_id as cat_id, subcat_name as cat_name
        from phpbb_dm_eds_subcat
    ) as bc
LEFT JOIN phpbb_dm_eds bd ON bd.download_cat_id = bc.cat_id
GROUP BY bc.cat_id   ;
```

(Your SELECT is using a MySQL extension, because cat_id is neither in the GROUP BY nor in an aggregate.)

Comment: I will read your "answer", which you should instead edit into your question, to learn more about what you want, but read my comment on your question: you are not clear, use the English language to explain clearly what you want.

Comment: i dont want the last_download from EVERY subtable, i only want the last_download from every MAINCAT, if the maincat has a subcat with a download in it i will only the latest download from a subcat while only once the maincat is displayed so for example maincat[test] subcat[aaa]]download=file.pdf] subcat[bbb][download=readme.txt]  it should only display maincat=test download=readme.txt if readme.txt is the newest file from readme.txt or file.pdf ... hope to be clear

Comment: You are not clear. How does one determine whether "the maincat has a subcat"?? Read my comments and do what they say. Do not hope, act.

Comment: the subcats has a field named "parent_id" in it desc phpbb_dm_eds_subcat;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| subcat_id   | int(9)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| parent_id   | int(9)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| subcat_name | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Answer (score 0):

From your notes"the 'test' category has a subcategory" ,i suggest there should be a relation between cat table "phpbb_dm_eds_cat" and sub_cat table
"phpbb_dm_eds_subcat".

Like this:
**Table name**
phpbb_dm_eds_cat
**Columns**
(cat_id,cat_name)

**Tablename**
phpbb_dm_eds_subcat
**Columns**
(cat_id referencing table phpbb_dm_eds_cat(cat_id),subcat_id,subcat_name)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly your query doesn't work, it gives me ALL subcats, like this:

```
+----------+--------+------------------+---------------+
| cat_name | cat_id | number_downloads | last_download |
+----------+--------+------------------+---------------+
| catx     |      9 |                1 |    1427072549 |
| cat2     |     10 |                1 |    1427125950 |
| test     |     11 |                0 |          NULL |
| aaa      |     39 |                0 |          NULL |
| xxx111   |     40 |                0 |          NULL |
| TESTXX   |     41 |                1 |    1427123713 |
| xxa      |     42 |                1 |    1427136789 |
+----------+--------+------------------+---------------+
7 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

I don't want the subcats to be displayed, I only want the last download from the subcat, this should be the correct output:

```
+----------+--------+------------------+---------------+
| cat_name | cat_id | number_downloads | last_download |
+----------+--------+------------------+---------------+
| catx     |      9 |                1 |    1427072549 |
| cat2     |     10 |                1 |    1427125950 |
| test     |     11 |                1 |    1427213321 |
+----------+--------+------------------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: i think there should be some left join or something similarf to identify in which maincat the subcat is in , as long as i want only the maincats displayed and need to get the value from a subcat in each maincat

Comment: 1. Edit this "answer" into your question. 2. Why does 'test' last_download differ from all subcategory last_downloads?